# Localhost Redirected you too many times DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, cookies, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I have a DotNetNuke application I am trying to setup on localhost.

The application was working fine until I tried to change database connection. After reverting back the changes I made in conenctionStrings, I am getting error whenever I try to run it. The error is

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Well, obiously I tried clearing cookies and also tried on multiple browsers but getting same result. Page is not working.

What can be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any source code the best answer I can give you is this, something in your code if forcing a redirect to iteself, which then forces another redirect to itself, etc.

It would basically by the same as doing this,

```
void DoSomething() {
    // Infinite loop, activate!
    DoSomething();
}
```

If you provide some source code or a link to it in the question I could give you a more detailed solution, but as the question stands this is the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only reason I haven't source code before I didn'y chage anything except `ConnectionString` in `web.config`. As for your suggestion, I already tried if there's any redirection in code and none found.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago, setting the trust level to full trust (in web.config) solved it for me.

Happy DNNing!
Michael